Warning interpretation when running a GAM using factor by smooths and also using bs="fs" for each individual subject
I would like to see how metabolite levels vary per treatment variable ( here antibiotics) over time. There are two levels (yes/no). When I run the below model 1, using bs="fs" it gets the following warning:
 Warning message:
   In gam.side(sm, X, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) :
   model has repeated 1-d smooths of same variable.


 model1 <- gam(Met1 ~ Antibiotics + s(Timepoint, k=7) +
                    s(Timepoint, by=Antibiotics, k=7, m=1) + 
                    s(Timepoint, ID_new, bs="fs", k=7) + data=pos_fullnew, method="REML")

Alternatively, removing the common trend s(Timepoint), to get the below runs without warning.
 model2 <- gam(Met1 ~ Antibiotics +
                    s(Timepoint, by=Antibiotics, k=7) + 
                    s(Timepoint, ID_new, bs="fs", k=7) + data=pos_fullnew, method="REML")

Any advice on the error/model would be appreciated - thank you.

Just ignore it; it's entirely harmless in this situation. It arises because s(x) and s(x, f, bs = "fs") are both seen as 1-d smooths of x. Normally that would be a big problem, but the "fs" basis is fully penalized, meaning if necessary the entire set of smooths can be shrunk out of the model.
by smooths aren't warned about, presumably because Simon envisaged having s(x) + s(x, by = f) smooths in the model and didn't flag that.
Your first model might be better parameterized as:
model1 <- gam(Met1 ~ s(Timepoint, k=7) +
                s(Timepoint, Antibiotics, k=7, bs = "sz") + 
                s(Timepoint, ID_new, bs="fs", k=7),
              data=pos_fullnew, method="REML")

using the new "sz" basis, where the first smooth, s(Timepoint) is the average smooth, the s(Timepoint, Antibiotics) smooth is a difference smooth for each level of Antibiotics relative the the average smooth. Note that this new basis includes the groups means, hence no need for the Antibiotics parametric term. This "sz" basis is fully orthogonal to the average smooth so we don't need the m = 1 fudge that we used on the by smooths.

Hopefully quick follow-up question: Could the sz basis be used (instead of by) when the main effect (s(Timepoint, k = 7) in this case) is not included in the model?
